# How can same user control render different output?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, user-controls

Ok. Here we go. I am not sure if anyone here has implemented this, but I have a user control in my Webforms application which I am calling on several forms.

This user control has a dropdown which calls the stored procedure and filters the dropdown according to a certain date. However, on one of the forms, I want same user control to still call the stored procedure but not filter at all, just fetch all records.

Basically, I want same user control to do one thing on one form and another thing on another form. I want to use same user control since there is only small change. Rest is the same and hence I want to avoid creating another form.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: `Is this possible?` yes, it is possible

Comment: I suppose you need to write some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is create a property on the user control:

```
public bool SOmeCOnfigurableSetting
{
  get { return ((bool?)ViewState[".."]).GetValueOrDefault(false); }
  set { ViewState[".."] = value; }
}
```

It can be any type, not just bool.  In each page, set the property on the user control definition, and this controls the filtering or other functionality.